# Removing life event from Facebook wall but keeping information under profile picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Is there a way to remove the "Started School at XYZ University" life event from your wall but still keep the "Studies at XYZ University" entry under your profile picture?

Answer (score 2):

Events are listed in Life Events when you enter a date on the event in the About section.  Remove the date info and it will no longer appear in Life Events.  To remove the date info, go to the item's date in About, click on the dropdown menu and change the year, month and day to "--".